# Multiple One-To-One relationships in same entity with YAML in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am designing one entity that should have two One To One relationships to two different tables. My main entity (Player) has these definitions:

```
oneToOne:
    attributesRegular:
        targetEntity: AttributesRegular
oneToOne:
    attributesNormalized:
        targetEntity: AttributesNormalized
```

Now in the AttributesRegular I have this: (similar to AttributesNormalized)

```
    oneToOne:
    player:
        targetEntity: Player
        inversedBy: attributesRegular
        joinColumn:
            name: player_id
            referenceColumnName: id
```

The problem is that when I generate the classes (and the DB schemas), only attributesNormalized is added, but not attributesRegular as well.

Can someone point to me what is wrong with my YML ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to state `oneToOne` once in Player otherwise you are rewriting the key/value rather than adding a value to it.

```
oneToOne:
    attributesRegular:
        targetEntity: AttributesRegular
    attributesNormalized:
        targetEntity: AttributesNormalized
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've just tried it and it works as expected. Does this "write once" apply to all other declarations?

Comment: Yeah. Essentially you are just creating an array with the yml file that is then parsed. So the keys, as in an array, should be unique.

Comment: Hi i have seen your solution. I need the exact solution as ANNOTATIONS. Please help me out.
class Student {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="StudentParentsGuardians", mappedBy="student")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="StudentSchoolInformation", mappedBy="student")
     */
    protected $studentParentsGuardians;
    protected $studentSchoolInformation;

Comment: You would need to put each annotation above the field that it is an association for.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply. Will you plz explain it with a small example. I'm a newbie to symfony. plz dont mind

Comment: The same way as in your example but with one annotation per variable. class Student { /** * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="StudentParentsGuardians", mappedBy="student") **/ protected $studentParentsGuardians; /*** * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="StudentSchoolInformation", mappedBy="student") */ protected $studentSchoolInformation;

Comment: thanks for your reply and i did the same thing. but when i'm executing this query
$student_si_row = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:StudentSchoolInformation')->findByStudentId($current_user_id);

it is going into an infinity loop & browser is getting closed. i checked the logs & it is saying maximum execution timedout.

Comment: You should open a new question. Your original question was about YAML mapping and now it has gone on to an issue about annotations and infinite loops.